# Ruby Capybara Element not found error handling

Tags: ruby, capybara

internet.find(:xpath, '/html/body/div[1]/div[10]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[2]/a').text

I am looping through a series of pages and sometimes this xpath will not be available. How do I continue to the next url instead of throwing an error and stopping the program? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, stop using xpaths like that - they're going to be ultra-fragile and horrendous to read. Without seeing the HTML I can't give you a better one - but at least part way along there has to be an element with an `id` you can target instead.

Next, you could catch the exception returned from `find` and ignore it or better yet you could check if page has the element first

```
if internet.has_xpath?(...)
  internet.find(:xpath, ...).text
   ...
else
   ... whatever you want to do when it's not on the page
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to accepted answer you could consider `#first` method that accepts `count` argument as the number of expected matches or `null` to allow empty results as well

```
internet.first(:xpath, ..., count: nil)&.text
```

That returns element's text if one's found and `nil` otherwise. And there's no need to ignore rescued exception

See [Capybara docs](https://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#first-instance_method)